# Loop products excluding on sale shows only 4 items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm retrieving the latest products **excluding on sale products** based on a code example that i found (the original retrieved on sale products only). This is what i did:

```
          <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'orderby' =>'id',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array( // Simple products type
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '=',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array( // Variable products type
                        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '=',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    )
                )
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
              <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Actually it's retrieving only 4 products (i need 8) and these are not the latests, but it's excluding on sale products correctly.

Any idea? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(edited) This will handle simple products. I'm tried to find how to handle variations but couldn't find any meta key that is set when you create a sale price. Anyway, the "compare" shouldn't be "OR" but should be "AND", since you wish to find the products that does not have any of these meta values.

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'orderby' =>'id',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    array( 
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'compare'       => 'NOT EXISTS',

                    ),
                )
            );
```

Comment: It retrieves the same response. I also tried with operator "=" instead of "=="

Comment: Thanks, i also found this and i'm actually using this combinated with your first recomendation `'key' => '_sale_price', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '='` because some products have this key created but nulled.